# require_once :failed to open stream: no such file or directory?

Tags: php

I have this testing code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook
```

My folders structure is this:

```
http://localhost/facebook.php
```

If i test this page in a browser i receive:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs/src/Facebook/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs/src/Facebook/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook.php on line 3
```

Comment: `http://localhost/facebook.php` this is not your folder structure

Comment: Sorry i keep my folder into C>xampp>htdocs>facebook.php but how can i fix my fetal error. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: where the autoload.php file is located or in which folder it is stored, please provide the full path, then only we can add the required path in require_once() function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named Facebook and put autoload.php inside that folder.  What is happening here is your facebook.php file is trying to include/load a file named autoload.php and it can't be found there that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: I will do it another way, anyway thank you for feedback.